# Devices that utilizes CISCO IOS Operating system

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios-12, cisco-ios-15, cisco-ios

I am a bit confused about the CISCO IOS operating system. My final year research project is based on solving some security vulnerabilities that i dug up that exists in the CISCO IOS, thus i need to find a CISCO router to implement my solution.

This is a very non technical question, but will any of you experts would be willing to help me to find a CISCO product that uses the CISCO IOS or does every product from CISCO use the CISCO IOS?

I tried searching in many ways but could find any :(

Thank you

Comment: See http://www.gns3.net/ that runs actual IOS code in a hardware simulator.

Comment: @generalnetworkerror thank you very much for that information :) if you please, could you tell me if there is an opensource version of firmware that i could use for devices (CISCO 800 series) that uses CISCO IOS operating system? like dd-wrt for standard adsl CISCO E2500/ E4200 routers?

Comment: I'm not familiar with opensource for Cisco h/w.  Perhaps @Mike Pennington could answer this.

Comment: @generalnetworkerror oh thank you very much for the info :)

Comment: Opensource Cisco... NO. That hasn't even been attempted since the days of the 2500 (which used a motorola 68000 cpu with no special ASICs) Those platforms have been dead (probably) longer than you've been alive.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cisco IOS is the standard operating system from Cisco. It runs on 800/1800/1900/2800/2900/3800/3900/7600 routers. It also runs on Catalyst 2960/3560/3750/4500/6500.

Some newer platforms such as Catalyst 3650 and 3850 run IOS XE which is IOS running as a daemon on a Linux kernel.

Then you have NXOS which runs on the Nexus platform.

IOS XR runs on the SP platforms such as ASR9k.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply :) much appreciated :) how about the CISCO VPN routers? do they run CISCO IOS? RV042/ RV082?

Comment: or the E1000/2000/4000 router series?

Comment: Those do not run IOS. Your best bet would be to use eBay to buy a router that supports the IOS version you wish to test.

Comment: @codey very much appreciate your reply! thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 6):

> I tried searching in many ways but could find any

http://www.cisco.com/go/fn

Cisco Feature Navigator -> Research Software

Select Software Type: "IOS"
Select your desired Major Release, and Release. The "Platform" drop down will then include every platform that is designed to run that release.

If you have a specific platform in mind, select "platform" under "search by". Then select your platform from the drop down.

Comment: I am kinda new to this whole thing and still in the initial phase of the research :) much appreciate you help on this :)

Comment: and sorry for the miss communication..much appreciate ur help :)